# asp.NET Web.config

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config

Hello guys i have an website online wich access the database. The database access for the connection String called GardenLadies is fine and works. I've added to the host database also the localsqlServer database info.
My problem is when i log in it gives me "Server Error in '/' Application.".

here´s my web config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="GardenLadies" connectionString="Database=GardenLadies.mdf; Data Source=195.22.11.199;Initial Catalog=GardenLadies;User ID=****;Password=*****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Database=GardenLadies.mdf; Data Source=195.22.11.199;Initial Catalog=GardenLadies;User ID=****;Password=****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I've used this formula of webconfig in other website and it has worked for me, i don't get what i'm missing here.

Thanks

This tells me that the problem is not the BD or the login, but an image that i use in masterpage.

"Access to the path 'E:\inetpub\vhosts\garden-ladies.pt\httpdocs\images\Imagens\fundo.jpg' is denied. "

I have other images in similar location but in anonymous pages.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us the rest of the error details?

Comment: Is the content of the YSOD in the post and just invisible due to a stray angle bracket? If not, please do post the content of the error.

Comment: First go to web config file and set <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors> then check what exact error you are getting and post that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys i've solved it, problem was with permissions in some folders in host.
Gave the permissions and everything worked.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a conflict with some information in your machine config.

What does your provider section look like?

AND why do you have two connection strings with the same info?  which is asking for issues.

Clear them all in your web config and set your default providers to use your GardenLadies connection string.